# Count and list the consecutive years for 10 years

Tags: forms, ee, date-format, drop-down

I would like to know if I can do this using ee or if I have to implement a PHP method. Basically I want a dropdown that lists years from the current year to the next ten years so: 2014, 2015, 2016 ..... until 2024. I want this to obviously change annually without me having to actually add ten years in the list every time it should just loop through.

I know I can get the year using this:

```
{current_time format="%Y"}
```

So are there things I can add or do to this date to get the dropdown I want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless it's been introduced in a recent version there is no way to do date arithmetic using native EE tags.

As you say you could do this with a fairly simple bit of PHP which could be added directly to a template or, as is probably better, wrapped up into a plugin. There may well already be something like this available on Devot:ee. For instance, try http://devot-ee.com/add-ons/dt-plugin

Comment: Yes I've found nothing that ee can do in this regard. Rather created a function.